# VSCode when trying to install the C# Extension it errors out saying unable to install dependecies

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup unity with VScode I got told to install the C# Extension to make it auto complete unitys code, but it errors out when I try to install C#, here is the error, I am on a linux system I dont know if that has anything to do with it.

```
Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: linux, x86_64, name=manjaro, version=unknown

Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (linux / x64)' Failed to download from https://github.com/Samsung/netcoredbg/releases/download/1.2.0-825/netcoredbg-linux-bionic-amd64.tar.gz. Error code '404')
    Retrying from 'https://web.archive.org/web/20201125201611/https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/113926796/2a979180-2f1f-11eb-8254-5746e29dc86d?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20201125%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201125T201611Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=16e82fadc53b2c8965a4921f7b4241df4b7d8ec1366d08a2e47d5ad840c80444&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=113926796&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dnetcoredbg-linux-bionic-amd64.tar.gz&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream' (NaN KB) Done!
Installing package '.NET Core Debugger (linux / x64)'

Failed at stage: installPackage
C# Extension was unable to install its dependencies. Please check your internet connection. If you use a proxy server, please visit https://aka.ms/VsCodeCsharpNetworking
```

How can I fix this, it wont install and keeps retrying to install but fails every time, it says something about my connect but its just fine so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this instructions:

[Install And Configure VSCode for Linux](https://medium.com/@sami1592/set-up-visual-studio-code-for-unity-in-linux-69b7f4352e0b)

After doing all this, if intellisense doesn't work open VS Code, go to menu File - Preferences - Settings - Extension - C# configuration
look for "Omnisharp: Use Global Mono", and set it to "always".

After that close VSCode and then re-open it.

Comment: thank you very much setting it to always fixed it, not sure why its like this maybe because its on linux, thanks again!